# How to get intermediate output when using tf.keras.application

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

`tf.keras.application` contains many famous neural network link `VGG`, `densenet`, `mobilenet` and so on. Take `tf.keras.application.MobileNet` as an example, what I am interested in is not only the final output, but also the output of the intermediate layer, how could I get all these output when retraining the network.

May be `model.get_output_at(index)` helps. However, every time I call this function, I get a `DeferredTensor` because I cannot forward the data at the same time. Does a convenient way exists?

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you to read the keras [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer):

One simple way is to create a new `Model` that will output the layers that you are interested in:

```
from keras.models import Model

model = ...  # create the original model

layer_name = 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                                 outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

Alternatively, you can build a Keras function that will return the output of a certain layer given a certain input, for example:

```
from keras import backend as K

# with a Sequential model
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                  [model.layers[3].output])
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([x])[0]
```

Similarly, you could build a Theano and TensorFlow function directly.

Note that if your model has a different behavior in training and testing phase (e.g. if it uses Dropout,  BatchNormalization, etc.), you will need to pass the learning phase flag to your function:

```
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
                                  [model.layers[3].output])

# output in test mode = 0
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([x, 0])[0]

# output in train mode = 1
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([x, 1])[0]
```

**Here is another similar answer written by [fchollet](https://twitter.com/fchollet?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor) himself:**
[How can I get hidden layer representation of the given data?](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/41)

Comment: Thanks~. However, I am using [tensorflow.keras module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras), not keras, do these two  things share the same API?

Comment: They do, I just tried using tensorflow 2.0 and got intermediate outputs using the first method above.